# Sequlize.js: .update does not return affected rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to change the `status` and get back the affected row:

```
db.Member.update({
            status: 0
        }, {
                where: {
                    id: member.id,
                    group_id: member.group_id,
                }
            }).then((updatedMember) => {
                console.log("Member" + updatedMember)
                // This returns 'Member 1', 
                // and the in the DB, the status field does change to 0

            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("err " + err)
            })
```

inside the `.then` block, I get `updatedMember` as `1`.  Also, if I change the `status` to something else that's not a field in the table, i.e. `joe: 0`, `updatedMember`still returns a `1`.

Question:

1. Can `.update` return the affected object?
2. If I am trying to change a field that doesn't exist in the table, should I get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using postgres, and only if, ...

According to the documentation (http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows), the update function returns an array of two objects, the first is the number of affected rows, and the second is the actual affected row (but only if you are using postgres). If you are using mysql, it won't work.

Thus, I think you can change your code to the following and it should work:

```
db.Member.update({
        status: 0
    }, {
            where: {
                id: member.id,
                group_id: member.group_id,
            }
        }).then((updatedMember) => {


            //updatedMember[0] will now be 1, updatedMember[1] should be the affected row


            console.log("Member" + updatedMember[1])

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("err " + err)
        })
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am using MySQL and the docs say `while the second element is the actual affected rows (only supported in postgres with options.returning true.)`  I believe I'll have to fallback to `.find` then `.update`.  I did try the second param, but it comes back `undefined`.

Comment: I had to update my original response a couple of times, as I read it over again and tried it out. I wish Sequelize documentation was a little more clear. I couldn't tell originally whether the parenthetical meant that it was only supported in postgres when the options were set, meaning it works everywhere else without options or if it only works in postgres with options set period. I tried myself in a project of my own and found out it was the latter. Mysql won't do it. Sorry